# Session variable in PHP, a number, passing to anther PHP script not working

Tags: php

I have one simple script that is to pass the number 15 on to the other script that is called, and it needs to be in the sleep() statement. It is not working and it also messes up the second script so the last line in the 2nd script does not execute. The 2nd script dials the linphone, phone call connects, it waits 15 seconds then kills the linphone daemon by the exec("killit"); If I manually put the 15 in that sleep statement, my linphone dialing script works perfect but when I try to put the 15 in to the sleep by using session variable passing, the phone call only stays up for 9 seconds (which is also wrong, should be 15 and I don't know where the 9 is coming from in seconds) and the last line to automatically kill the linphone daemon doesn't work, I have to do it by command line. That last line is actually a small script in C that has the bash shell script in it to do a pkill of linphone, of which I learned from here.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['15'];
header('Location: linphone.php');

-------------------------------

session_start();
$output1=shell_exec ("linphonecsh init");
sleep(1);
$output2=shell_exec ("linphonecsh register --host 142.100.64.220  --username 5555 --password 5555");                     
sleep(2);
$output=shell_exec ("linphonecsh dial 3001@142.100.64.220");
sleep($_SESSION);
exec("killit");
```

I have tried this syntax as well, from this site, but does not work.

```
session_start();
$wait = (15);
$_SESSION['timer'] = $wait;

session_start();
$sec = $_SESSION['timer'];
sleep($sec);
```

Comment: what do you expect from `$_SESSION['15'];` to be doing?

Comment: the second try looks much better, stick on that. What part _"but does not work"_ in this version?

Comment: Did I write that wrong here? I need the number 15 put into the $_SESSION, But if I mistakenly did write that one wrong, I think the bottom syntax should be correct, which also doesn't work as explained..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$_SESSION[15]` doesn't do anything. `$_SESSION` is a global array so you have to set a `[key]` and a `value`. Try setting a `$_SESSION['timer']` variable to 15 and passing that. As below.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['timer'] = 15;
header('Location: linphone.php');


session_start();
$output1=shell_exec ("linphonecsh init");
sleep(1);
$output2=shell_exec ("linphonecsh register --host 142.100.64.220  -- 
username 5555 --password 5555");                     
sleep(2);
$output=shell_exec ("linphonecsh dial 3001@142.100.64.220");
sleep((int) $_SESSION['timer']);
exec("killit");
```

Comment: looks good, an explanation of what you've changed and why would be nice though!

Comment: Added in the edit. Was just getting an answer down first in case you were under time pressure.

Comment: Somethings up with the sleep function, like its messing things up or gets messed up on the session variable pass. There isn't much written on sleep except putting a number in there for seconds. So the int would be like telling sleep there is a number there? I wrote it like your example, which looks golden, but the phone call only stays up for 9 seconds versus 15 if I put 15 in manually in sleep(15). The last line to exec("killit") does not work at all, but it does when I manually put 15 in sleep. I have no idea where the 9 seconds is coming from or why the exec fails this way.

Comment: Well, you are 100% correct in you answer, thank you. Having tried everything over and over I had exec("killit") when it should have been exec("./killit"). Now that is fixed, I proved the session variable pass for sleep works perfect, I just need to find out why the SIP phone call drops after 9 seconds no matter what you put in there for sleep. Thats a SIP thing and one thing I am good at is SIP so I will figure that one out. Thanks!!

Comment: No problem, yes I added the `(int)` as a way of ensuring the variable is cast as a number, in case there was any typing issue causing your 9 second problem. But looks like you can remove it.